# Ubuntu 14.04 with internet connection sharing internet to Win XP vitualbox

Tags: wireless, networking, virtualbox, internet, windows-xp

I've looked through the posted questions and there are a lot of topics about sharing guest's e.g. Win XP connection to Ubuntu host.

What I'm actually looking is if there is a way to share Ubuntu's (host) internet connection to guest's (Win XP), I use Xubuntu netbook with wi-fi to share internet to Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop through LAN cable, it works pretty well, but... I need to run this program which I wasn't able to run through Wine on Ubuntu, so I followed given advice and installed Virtualbox with Win XP on it... Now the problem is I do not have internet connection on that guest Win XP in Virtualbox, but I really need it.

SO the question is if there is a way to do this kind of thing and how can I establish internet connection from Ubuntu 14.04 host to Win XP guest in Virtualbox?

All help will be much appreciated. Sorry if I didn't see already existing forum topic, I tried to look it up, but didn't find the needed information.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You have a LAN cable between Xubuntu host and Ubuntu guest? Where did you install the XP guest, on Xubuntu host? You have an XP program to establish internet connectivity? If so, then you have the internet only on XP? Then why are all tips on how to use a guest's internet access on the host useless?

Comment: Well it is like this. I run Xubuntu netbook which is through wi-fi connected to the internet. Then I have plugged a LAN cable from that Xubuntu netbook to the Desktop on which I run Ubuntu 14.04. So I share my wi-fi internet to the desktop pc. To do this I go to Edit Connections>IPv4 Settings>Share to other computers.

Comment: So in the end I have internet on my Ubuntu 14.04 as well. Then I have installed Virtualbox on which I run Win Xp (because of this prog I can't run through Wine). And I want to establish internet from my Ubuntu 14.04 host to that Win XP guest. I am wondering if it is possible at all and if so How can I do that, a some kind of manual (preferrably detailed one) would be very welcome.

Comment: All this because I do not have a wi-fi card on my desktop, if I had I'd partitioned my Hdd and installed both Ubuntu and Win Xp on it, but as I only can have internet connection through my wi-fi on Xubuntu netbook, and so on Ubuntu as I have described how, I can't run Win XP and Ubuntu dual boot, because I will only have internet connection on Ubuntu and not on the Win XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work out of the box. Shutdown the guest, and in the Virtualbox manager, add a virtual network card to it. Set the network type to "NAT". Start the guest again - the virtual computer should recognize the card and have network access on it. (You may need to install the Virtualbox additions in the guest.)

Comment: YOU rock mate! YOu were right straight away, all I had to do was to try out different adapter types! And voila it works, thank you a lot!! This forum rocks :)

Comment: I already had Virtualbox additions installed, I used it for sharing host's folders to guest, this informations is for those who will re-read this post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to share the internet connection. In fact it should work out of the box. Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking) for some Documentation.

Comment: You were absolutely right too!! All I had to do was to try some different adapter types and it started to work!! Thank you for your answer.